# Why does an absolute position element wrap based on its parent's right bound?

Tags: css

Why does an absolutely positioned element depend on its parent for text wrapping? Doesn't `position: absolute` remove an element from the flow?

[image: Why does this text wrap around, even though this container has been removed from the flow of its parent?]

I'm looking to remove this boundary. This is like an implied `max-width` that I don't want; I want another developer to be able to set this `max-width`, and not worry about this arbitrary bound. How do I remove this behavior?

For convenience, [here is a jsbin](http://jsbin.com/livacelu/1).

Comment: Well your parent is also positioned absolutely

Comment: Yes, but when I played around with it, it didn't seem to matter whether the parent was positioned or not.

Comment: I checked in firefox and it matters for sure, at least on FF. Which browser did you check with? Also the definition for your custom elements might not be defined correctly, as I get different behaviours when I change them to divs

Comment: The latest stable build of Chrome.

Comment: I get different layouts when removing the position absolute from parent on chrome

Comment: Are you saying you're having an issue with the DOM hierarchy? Of course a child element is relative to the parent element, unless you use attributes like "left:-50px". If you don't want it to be affected, take the child out of the parent!

Comment: I just checked in Firefox, and it did not make a difference. Statically placing the parent causes the parent to be as wide as the page. Relatively positioning the parent causes the parent's right bound to be further left. Regardless, the child is still based on the parent's right bound.

Comment: @uber5001 You must of been mistaken, you have defined width for the parent, how could it take up the width of the page? http://jsbin.com/livacelu/11/edit note I changed the elements to divs

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "remove this boundary". What do you want it to look like?

Comment: I was expecting the child to have no "preferred width". i.e.: The text would flow off the page to the right until a `max-width` was hit.

Comment: @uber5001 in the case where the parent is positioned statically, the width will be calculated based on the body since there are no other parents. I guess you can read through the specs for more details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Doesn't `position: absolute` remove an element from the flow?

This has nothing to do with the flow. The width of an element always respects its containing block. If the element is absolutely positioned, then its dimensions can be constrained by `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left`, but as long as its `width` is `auto` then it must still be constrained to the width of its containing block (making it no different from in-flow block boxes in that respect), which in your case is its absolutely-positioned parent. There isn't really any other element whose constraints the absolutely-positioned element could size itself with respect to without compromising the flow of its text.

For the specifics of how this width is calculated, refer to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width).

Comment: I read through most of section 9 looking for that reference! Don't know why I didn't think to look in details. Thanks.

Comment: Huh. That spec gives way to a hacky solution: `margin-right: -999999px;`. I don't like how that solution looks in code, but it works!

Comment: @uber5001: I edited my answer to include what I think is a more sensible solution ;) It does assume the content is text, however, because if the contents are blocks, then it should still overflow as normal.

Comment: You're referring to using `white-space: nowrap`? That would cause the text to NOT wrap regardless of whether a developer sets a limiting `max-width`. The text would overflow out of its container.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="absolute-parent">
    <div id="absolute-child">
      Why does this text wrap around, even though this container has been removed from the flow of its parent?
    </absolute-child>
  </absolute-parent>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body * {
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
#absolute-child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 40px;
}
#absolute-parent {
  /*position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;*/
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

I removed the positioning from the absoluet parent element and also turned that and the child element into divs with ids.