# css - parent's position is absolute and child's position is relative and vice versa

Tags: css, css-position

I have div which hosts another div. Ok, I get the case when the parent is `position:relative` and
the child is `position:absolute`. I don't get what happens when

1. parent's position is absolute and child's position is relative
2. parent's position is absolute and child's position is absolute
3. parent's position is relative and child's position is relative

I use the [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/livacelu/1) example from [Why does an absolute position element wrap based on its parent's right bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307922/why-does-an-absolute-position-element-wrap-based-on-its-parents-right-bound) but the question applies to positioning concept in general

Comment: Isn't point #1 and #3 identical?

Comment: You don't get what happens to what?

Comment: @Terry: yes, and #2 is the same as the case that the OP understands – positioning takes into account the closest non-static parent.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[Read more about absolute, relative, and fixed position and how they differ here](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/), but I'll try to answer your question about relationships specifically.

`position: absolute` will position that element to its **nearest parent with a `position` other than `static`**. Static is the default for everything.

`position: relative` is a little weird because it really affects that element's children, not its own position. It's just saying to its child elements, "position yourself relative to me if you have `position: absolute`." A `position` of `fixed` or `absolute` does the same thing (meaning its positioned children will position themselves relative to its boundaries), but these styles also affect their own position on the page. An element with `position: relative` won't look any different, but its children might.

So consider a situation like this:

```
<div class="parent">
     <div class="child">
           <div class="grandchild"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

If `grandchild` has `position: absolute`, it will position itself relative to the browser window because there is no parent with a `position` other than the default of `static`.

If `parent` also has `position` of `relative`, `absolute`, or `fixed`, `grandchild` will position itself relative to the boundaries of `parent`.

However, if `child` also has a `position` of `relative`, `absolute`, or `fixed`, the `grandchild` will position itself relative to `child`'s boundaries, because *it* is the nearest parent with a `position` other than `static`.

In summary, `relative` affects an element's children, while `absolute` and `fixed` affect the element itself as well as its children.

And remember that `position: fixed` bypasses all `relative` and `absolute` parents and always positions itself relative to the browser window.

Comment: Since this is the accepted answer, let me state here for the record that _"`position: relative` is a little weird because it really affects that element's children, not it's own position."_ is not all true. You can change a relative element's location on the screen with the `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` properties in a way you can't do with other values for `position`.

Comment: Yeah, but he just mentioned the use of barely the position: relative property without setting those 4 properties. It's just a way of telling the child elements..."Hey, you can do your measures based on me, and my position will not change if I only use position:relative"

Comment: @Barry T. Smith (or a mod with sufficient privileges): Could you please fix your incorrect use of the possessive form of "its" in your answer? Possessive "its" is written without an apostrophe. The only cases in which "it's" gets an apostrophe is in the contraction of "it is" or "it has." It's very disorienting to read an answer with confusing grammatical errors. See: http://its-not-its.info/

Comment: I have a div[position:relative] with two children div[position:absolute]. Now the div[position:relative] has height 0px causing elements next to it to be put on the child elements

Comment: I found a fix for it (this works because both children are of same height and I want second one to wrap the other). I simply made the second child as position:absolute and let the first one be default

Answer (score 4):

- If the mommy is relative and the child is absolute : the mommy listens to her child. as if to protect him. sort of..
- If they are both absolute : they have nothing to do with each other. they are strangers to each other.
- If the parent is absolute and child relative : they are bound. the child moves ( width and height ) towards or away from his mommy.

It will always be a little strange, there are a lot of great texts about this, but also for me it is always just switching absolute and relative until it works. hope this clears it up a little.

Comment: Hi Bas,
Hoping you can help me get my children inline. 
They refuse to be contained by their parents.
Let me outline their background:
They are children of colour, and all if them are wrapping.
I think I need to set up some margins for them, as at the moment they have no borders at all.
Perhaps they just need a some style?
At the moment they're not very animated and struggling with transitions.
None of their ancestors had these issues.
Do I just need to be more flexible?

Comment: just send me a link and i'll try to help you