# HTML/CSS/Javascript: Force child elements to never exceed parent size without modifying children

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i like how the iframes neatly contain all site data inside the frame and fit it to size. Is there any way to generate this behaviour in an html wrapper? set up the wrapper in such a way that no matter what, the contents are displayed within its size formatting, without modifying the child elements in any way manually?

Comment: please include your initial code and what have you tried so far. a fiddle would be better.

Comment: You only have to specify the width at the parent container (if I understood your question)

Comment: CSS `overflow: auto;`. See this [**link**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)! I guess that's what you want!

Comment: @GeomanYabes not really, because when i google this questions people have asked it before and ended up getting a custom response to the elements they were trying to contain. As i am asking about a globally consistent way to achieve this (if it is possible at all) I chose to omit code to prevent people answering in such a manner.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir this does not work for child divs with `position: fixed`

Comment: @WobbaFetttttt then use `overflow: scroll;` to force it!

Comment: An iframe is an independent window instance with its own viewport - so all media queries (and that would be the main part of what you mean when you say _“the contents are displayed within its size formatting”_, I guess) would use the iframe width as their basis. Achieving _that_ with normal HTML elements is currently not possible; “element media queries” is the name given to a proposed solution that some people have thought up, but that is not implemented in any browser yet.

Comment: @CBroe thanks so much for the name drop buddy. that helped me lot!

Answer (score 0):

Set the size (width and height) and use overflow:hidden. If the child exceed the size the content is hidden.

Comment: that merely hides the contents, not squeeze them. also it doesnt work for child divs with `position: fixed`

Comment: Nice to know, never had that case ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can put your content in a `<div>` and then manipulate it:

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

Notice the `position: relative`! That's important when you have elements inside with `position: absolute`! Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26981592/3130281), also a quote from [here](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/):

> Absolute. This is a very powerful type of positioning that allows you to literally place any page element exactly where you want it. You use the positioning attributes top, left bottom and right to set the location. **Remember that these values will be relative to the next parent element with relative (or absolute) positioning.**

Alternatively, if you're talking about squeezing the whole page "like an `<iframe>`", you can modify the `<html>` and `<body>` tags. **I don't think that's good practice, though.**

With `margin: 0 auto` you can center the page.
With `overflow: auto` you enable scrolling so that the content doesn't go outside the page.

```css
html, body {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following two CSS properties

**This will not allow the content to exceed the container**

```
.container{
   overflow : hidden;
   width : <size>;
   height : <size>;
}
```

**This will automatically add scrollbars to the container when the content exceeds the size of the container**

```
.container{
   overflow : auto;
   width : <size>;
   height : <size>;
}
```