# Display flex, align a div in the bottom right corner of its container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to display yellow div "icon" on the bottom/right corner of its red container "content".

What is wrong in my script?

```css
.root {
    display: inline-flex;
    background-color: red;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    align-items: centerl;
    justify-content: centerl;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
    <div class="content">
        content
    </div>
    <div class="icon">
      icon
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of position you can achieve using flex end property `align-self: flex-end;`

see below code snippet:

```css
.root {
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: red;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.icon {
   align-self: flex-end;
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="content">
    content
  </div>
  <div class="icon">
    icon
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: **align-items:center**  defines the default behaviour for how flex items are laid out along the cross axis on the current line. You can think of it as the justify-content version for the cross-axis and **justify-content:center**  defines items are centered along the line.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.root {
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: centerl;
  justify-content: centerl;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom:0;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="content">
    content
  </div>
  <div class="icon">
    icon
  </div>
</div>
```

add in .root element

```
position: relative;
```

Comment: why relative is necessary?

Comment: @Radex check [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26979386/css-parents-position-is-absolute-and-childs-position-is-relative-and-vice-ve) for clearer explanation

Comment: @Radex So that absolute positions stay within that element without going out.

Answer (score 1):

In the HTML structure you presented the `.icon` element is not **inside** the `.container` element. So it cannot be related to it. If you change the structure and give the `.container` element `position: relative`, it will work.

```css
.root {
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: red;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: centerl;
  justify-content: centerl;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom:0;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="content">
    content
    <div class="icon">
      icon
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```