# Meaningless character in css

Tags: html, css

I'm new to web development and learning how to align elements to vertical centre. This is what I found, but it doesn't work. However if I add some meaningless characters in css, it'll work perfectly fine, including fullstops, comma, etc. I tried on Safari and Chrome and they behaved in the same way. Does these character mean anything?

Original solution:

```
<head>
    <style>
        #parent {
            position: relative;}
        #child {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            height: 30%;
            width: 50%;

        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="parent">
        <div id="child">Content here</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Solution with meaningless character:

```
<head>
    <style>
        #parent {
            ,
            position: relative;}
        #child {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            height: 30%;
            width: 50%;

        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Comment: That's because the "meaningless characters" are breaking the CSS for `#parent` so it is acting exactly the same as if you deleted the CSS for `#parent` altogether. Without the characters, the CSS is working as it is mean to - it is displaying centred inside the parent div (which has no height so child will be positioned at the top of the page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it happens Because those characters are breaking the CSS for that element "#parent" it's like it's not there see my example

```css
    #child {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            height: 30%;
            width: 50%;

        }
```

```html
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="parent">
        <div id="child">Content here</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The comma invalidates the CSS style #parent because it's improper syntax.  The CSS parser on browsers will just skip over it.  It's the same as if you had just

```
<head>
    <style>
        #child {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            height: 30%;
            width: 50%;

        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="parent">
        <div id="child">Content here</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Why it works once you remove the #parent style is another matter explained here [css - parent's position is absolute and child's position is relative and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26979386/css-parents-position-is-absolute-and-childs-position-is-relative-and-vice-ve)

Answer (score 1):

you should move the `#parent` instead of the `#child`

1. Move the parent box not the child.
2. `#parent{ position: absolute;}` is inherinting from `<body>`
3. `#child {position: relative;}` is inheriting from `#parent`
4. `HAPPY CODE! KEEP IT UP` :)

[image: Browser View]

```css
#parent {
    border: 10px solid green;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    top: 50%;
  
}

#child {
    border: 5px solid red;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">Content here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIo3u.png)

As you can see in my screenshot that character makes position: relative invalid value.
I would like to recommand you Developer tools ([enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools)) so you can see css for particular tags when you click on them.